# Ocultar o mostrar un div con un boton react

Tags: reactjs

Buen día! Tengo 2 div y 2 botones un boton es para que se muestre el segundo div y se muestre el primer div; el segundo boton es para que se oculte segundo div y se muestre el primero.

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {checked: false}
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

handleChange(checked) {
    this.setState({ checked});
  }
render() {
        return (

<div className="col-md-6  mb-2">
   <div className="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">

{/* Este es el boton 1 */}
      <button type="button" id="btn-nquote" className="btn btn-success btn-sm" onClick={this.handleChange} checked={this.state.checked}>Normal Quote</button>

{/* Este es el boton 2 */}
      <button type="button" id="btn-flex" className="btn btn-unique btn-sm" onClick={this.handleChange} checked={this.state.checked}>Flex Quote</button>
   </div>
 </div>

{/* Este es el div 1 */}
<div hidden={this.state.checked ?  false : true}></div>

{/* Este es el div 2 */}
<div hidden={this.state.checked ?  false : true}></div>
 );
}
```

Mi problema es que al presionar cualquiera de los dos botones me oculta el segundo div y ya no puedo volver a mostrar el primer div al presionar cualquiera de los dos botones.

Espero me puedan ayudar y quedo atento

Comment: lo que quieres hacer es algo asi http://www.spotcloud.io/#technologies???

Comment: si, precisamente así amigo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hola aqui ya te hice el codigo, la pagina que te puse es mia, esta TODA echa en react no fue nada facil mas esa parte pero aquí te lo dejo

el primer botón muestra un div, y el segundo botón oculta el primer div y muestra el segundo div
si es así aquí te hice el código

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Ejemplo extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { checked: false };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(checked) {
    this.setState({ checked });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="col-md-6  mb-2">
          <div
            className="btn-group btn-group-sm"
            role="group"
            aria-label="Basic example"
          >
            {/* Este es el boton 1 */}
            <button
              type="button"
              id="btn-nquote"
              className="btn btn-success btn-sm"
              onClick={() => this.handleChange(false)}
            >
              Normal Quote
            </button>

            {/* Este es el boton 2 */}
            <button
              type="button"
              id="btn-flex"
              className="btn btn-unique btn-sm"
              onClick={() => this.handleChange(true)}
            >
              Flex Quote
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <span>
          {this.state.checked ? (
            <div /* Este es el div 1 */ className="redd" />
          ) : (
            <div /* Este es el div 2 */ className="red2" />
          )}
        </span>


      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Ejemplo;
```

y le agregue estilos a los div para diferenciarlos

```
.redd{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
.red2{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
}
```

espero que te funcione, yo lo probé y me funciono

Comment: Te agradezco mucho solo era cuestión de agregar true y false en las funciones de mis botones tal como lo tienes en tu código. GRACIAS.

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo otra solución empleando un solo botón y haciendo uso de los [nuevos Hooks de React](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html). Espero tambien te sirva.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default () => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true);

  return (
    <>
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={() => {
          setShow(!show);
        }}
      >
        Mostrar {show ? 'Div 2' : 'Div 1'}
      </button>

      {show ? (
        <div style={{ color: 'red' }}>Div 1</div>
      ) : (
        <div style={{ color: 'blue' }}>Div 2</div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```